# Select2 apresentar valor do optgroup e option concatenado

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Estou criando um campo de seleção onde o usuário pode escolher entre vários estados, mas preciso que mostre quando selecionado tanto o valor do optgroup quanto do option, tem como?

Lembrando que estou usando a library select2

segue o html de base

```
<select name="estados[]" id="estados" multiple  style="width:300px">
    <optgroup label="Suldeste">
        <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
        <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
        <option value="MG">Minas Gerais</option>
        <option value="ES">Espírito Santo</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Sul">
        <option value="PR">Paraná</option>
        <option value="SC">Santa Catarina</option>
        <option value="RS">Rio Grande do Sul</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Nordeste">
        <option value="AL">Alagoas</option>
        <option value="BA">Bahia</option>
        <option value="CE">Ceará</option>
        <option value="MA">Maranhão</option>
        <option value="PB">Paraíba</option>
        <option value="PE">Pernambuco</option>
        <option value="PI">Piauí</option>
        <option value="RN">Rio Grande do Norte</option>
        <option value="SE">Sergipe</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Centro-Oeste">
        <option value="DF">Distrito Federal</option>
        <option value="GO">Goiás</option>
        <option value="MT">Mato Grosso</option>
        <option value="MS">Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Norte">
        <option value="AM">Amazonas</option>
        <option value="AC">Acre</option>
        <option value="RR">Roraima</option>
        <option value="RO">Rondônia</option>
        <option value="AP">Amapá</option>
        <option value="PA">Pará</option>
        <option value="TO">Tocantins</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

e a chamado do js para o select2 funcionar

```
$("#estados").select2();
```

segue um exemplo no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pb8b7f2b/)

perceba que quando se escolhe um estado ele mostra o nome do estado, mas precisaria que mostrasse tanto a região quanto o estado, por exemplo, Suldeste - São Paulo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui nessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037232/how-to-show-the-optgroup-value-option-value-as-the-selection) do So-Inglês trata seu problema,especificamente nesse [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/bJxFR/4/) que achei ser o melhor, porém só funciona com seleção simples.

Com ajuda do próprio Autor da Pergunta no [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pb8b7f2b/3) e com essa [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361197/optgroup-value-multiple-select-with-selected2/35369650#35369650) no So-Inglês adaptamos o código para funcionar para multiple select;

*Adicione:*

```
function format(item) {

      var el = item.element;        
    var og = $(el).closest('optgroup').attr('label');    
    return og+'-'+item.text;
}

$("#estados").select2({
    formatSelection: format,
    escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; }
});
```

Comment: Opa, dei uma olhada e com certeza já me da uma ajuda, mas tem alguma coisa estranha que acontece quando seleciono uma primeira opção, aparece como undefined o valor do label do optgroup, tem alguma ideia? da uma olhada nesse http://jsfiddle.net/pb8b7f2b/1/ atualizado

Comment: @MarceloDiniz tem que ser multipla seleção?

Comment: Nesse caso sim, pode ser que o usuário final escolher uma opção ou mais.

Comment: E se perceber, se escolher uma segunda opção ou até mais outras opções ele retorna sempre o primeiro label do optgroup

Comment: @MarceloDiniz entendi, esse código não funciona correta com multipla seleção.

Comment: da uma olhada nesse aqui http://jsfiddle.net/pb8b7f2b/3/ dai atualize sua resposta para eu marcar como válido, afinal foi com sua ajuda

Comment: @MarceloDiniz Ficou top. Se quiser editar pode ficar avontade. Tava tentando com um amigo no almoço, mais tava foda resolver. Bom que pude ajudar.

Comment: @MarceloDiniz Tinha feito até pergunta no So-Inglês. Olha ai. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361197/optgroup-value-multiple-select-with-selected2/35369650#35369650