# Select2 não seleciona

Tags: json, jquery-select2

Usando o plugin select2 via json não consigo selecionar nenhum resultado.
Quando seleciona ele nao exibe o resultado. Estou fazendo algo errado?

```
        $(".PessoaTipo").select2({
            language: "pt-BR",
            placeholder: "Pessoa Tipo",
            allowClear: true,
            minimumInputLength: 0,
            ajax:{
                url: base_url("system_data/pessoaTipo"),
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                delay: 150,
                data: function(params){
                    return{
                        text: params.term
                    };
                },
                processResults: function(data, params){
                    params.page = params.page || 1;     
                    return{
                        results: data,
                        pagination:{
                            more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                        }
                    };
                },
                cache: true
            }
        });

       <label class="lbPessoaTipo">Tipo</lab[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]el>
       <div class="select2 PessoaTipo"></div>
```

Comment: Tenho duas respostas sobre. Veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59727/como-deixar-a-primeira-op%C3%A7%C3%A3o-disabled-e-selecionada/59747#59747 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112747/select2-apresentar-valor-do-optgroup-e-option-concatenado/112775#112775. 
Seu erro está aqui  `<div class="select2 PessoaTipo"></div>`. Em vez de aplicar em div aplique em um select que já esteja carregado.

Comment: Mudei de div para select. Deu certo. Tnks!

Comment: Qui bom que pude ajudar :).